# Variable not being set properly in a nested for loop

Tags: batch-file, variables, nested-loops

I have searched countless posts about this topic and changed the code many times, but the end result of using the following (updated) code is always that the myfiledateNow variable is blank. Can anyone help? Thank you!

Code: (see results below)

```
@SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set themes=CDTNEW,CFTNEW
for %%z in (%themes%) do (
set "Now=C:\Users\psnider\Documents\Stuff\MISCELLANEOUS\ArchiveAurora\Files_Helper\%%~z_Now.csv"
for %%a in (!Now!) do (
  set myfiledateNow=%%~ta
)
)
```

Results:

```
C:\Users\psnider\Documents\Stuff\MISCELLANEOUS\ArchiveAurora>set themes=CDTNEW,C
FTNEW

C:\Users\psnider\Documents\Stuff\MISCELLANEOUS\ArchiveAurora>for %z in ("CDTNEW"
"CFTNEW") do (
set "Now=C:\Users\psnider\Documents\Stuff\MISCELLANEOUS\ArchiveAurora\Files_Help
er\%~z_Now.csv"
for %a in (!Now!) do (set myfiledateNow=%~ta )
)

C:\Users\psnider\Documents\Stuff\MISCELLANEOUS\ArchiveAurora>(
set "Now=C:\Users\psnider\Documents\Stuff\MISCELLANEOUS\ArchiveAurora\Files_Help
er\CDTNEW_Now.csv"
for %a in (!Now!) do (set myfiledateNow=%~ta )
)

C:\Users\psnider\Documents\Stuff\MISCELLANEOUS\ArchiveAurora>(set myfiledateNow=
)

C:\Users\psnider\Documents\Stuff\MISCELLANEOUS\ArchiveAurora>(
set "Now=C:\Users\psnider\Documents\Stuff\MISCELLANEOUS\ArchiveAurora\Files_Help
er\CFTNEW_Now.csv"
for %a in (!Now!) do (set myfiledateNow=%~ta )
)

C:\Users\psnider\Documents\Stuff\MISCELLANEOUS\ArchiveAurora>(set myfiledateNow=
)

C:\Users\psnider\Documents\Stuff\MISCELLANEOUS\ArchiveAurora>Pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: You should add a language tag to this.

Comment: Your results do not match the code you've provided. You have shown some code, and some results which fail  to meet your aspirations. Perhaps your question would be improved were you to tell us what you were hoping for in the results, or better still what your goal is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is the best I can provide based on your incomplete question.

```bat
Set "fDir=%UserProfile%\Documents\Stuff\MISCELLANEOUS\ArchiveAurora\Files_Helper"
For /F "Delims==" %%A In ('"(Set fDT[) 2>Nul"') Do Set "%%A="
For %%A In (CDTNEW,CFTNEW) Do For %%B In ("%fDir%\%%A_Now.csv") Do Set "fDT[%%A]=%%~tB"
Set fDT[ 2>Nul & Pause
```

Comment: To save you a little time, the second line is only used to un-set, _(undefine)_, any existing variable beginning with `fDT[`. It does that in order to exclude any existing variable from the output of `Set fDT`, _(you only see what you `Set` in the nested `For` loops particular command)_.

Comment: Thank you! That saved me a lot of time!  Marked as answer!